# Does complex conjugation commute with pull-backs?

Tags: proof-verification, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Let $\alpha$ be a complex $k$-form on $X$ and $f$ a smooth map between complex manifolds. Is then $$\overline{f^* \alpha} = f^* \overline \alpha$$

This is a local question, so we can assume $\alpha = g \,dz_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge d\bar z_{j_q}$ and $f=(f_1,\dots,f_n)$. So it suffices to check this on functions and on $dz_{i_1}$ and $d\bar z_{j_1}$

I think it is true on the coordinate 1-forms, because 
$\overline{f^* d z_i} = \overline {d f_i} = \bar d \overline{ f_i} = d \overline{ f_i}.$

But how is it for functions?
Is $\overline{f^* g} = \overline{g\circ f}$ the same as $f^* \bar g = \bar g \circ f$?

I thought, this was obvious, because $\bar f (z) = \overline {f(z)}$.
But then I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186991/complex-conjugate-of-complex-function) and got confused.

Edit: I saw that $f(x,y) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$ with $u,v$ real, so $\bar f = u - iv$.
I still think, it is true, but I begin to wonder, as I don't see it written in any of the books.

Comment: The most you can say is $\overline{f^* \alpha} =\overline { f^*} \overline \alpha$ . In complex geometry you have the tangent bundle and the "conjugate" tangent bundle. Conjugation moves between the two, but if you have something more complicated (like the linear $f^{*}$ transform from  $TX$ to $TY$ . ) then conjugation applies both to the domain and the co-domain. In summary, if something applies to non-conjugated things, then you can't plug in conjugated things as arguments. You have to conjugate the operation (eg. jacobian) itself, and the result will inherit the conjugation.

Comment: @user3257842: Doesn't a $(p,q)$-form pull back to (possibly a sum of) $(p',q')$-forms with $p+q=p'+q'$? And each of these forms can be conjugated separately?

Comment: Sorry. I've refreshed my memory on complex geometry . A $(p,q)$-form pulls back to a $(p,q)$-form. Its conjugate is a $(q,p)$ -form. A $(p,q)$-form can be interpreted as a formal sum of tensor products between  $p$-forms and conjugated $q$-forms.The $p$-forms are pulled back to $p$-forms with $f^{*}$ and the conjugated $q$-forms are pulled back to conjugated  $q$-forms with $\overline { f^*}$. So the pullback operation, when applied to $(p,q)$-forms, hides a lot of detail. The heuristic is to only apply conjugated functions to conjugated things. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexForm.html

Comment: And the reason behind the heuristic is how things transform in a coordinate change. Your aim by linear composition is to always obtain invariant things.You can compose a conjugated $1$-form field with a conjugated vector-field to obtain a scalar field(scalar fields don't transform when coordinates change, so they don't have an associated conjugation),or you can compose a non-conjugated $1$-form to a non-conjugated field. But you can't compose conjugated forms to non-conjugated fields because the coordinate transformations would not make sense.Like trying to compose a vector with a vector.

Comment: Given the mechanism by which $f^{*}$ acts on $(p,q)$-forms, the equation $\overline{f^* \alpha} = f^* \overline \alpha$ is correct.

Comment: A $(p,q)$-form certainly doesn't pull back to a $(p,q)$-form under a general smooth mapping. This is true when $f$ is a holomorphic map between complex manifolds. Consider $f(z)=\bar z$, $f\colon\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$, with the usual complex structure on $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Is the rest still true though?